# How to put a vertical line inside a EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a edit text and I want to out a line and the buttons like this: [image]

I want to put he buttons too. If anyone know how to do this I appreciate the help.
How to put the line and how to avoid the text to cross the line?

Comment: I think whole thing might not be inside an EditText. You may have o design a Layout schema for creating something like above.

Comment: yeah you are probably looking at and edittext with a certain width then buttons next to it

Comment: I did the line. i added a imageview inside the edittext. But the text is going under the line.

Comment: How to avoid the text go under the imageview?

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is a compound layout of your own construction.  Something like:

[image: red boxes are view children]

One top level linear layout with the text view, a line drawable, and another LinearLayout which holds (vertically) the '160/1', the clip button, and the 'Enviar' button.

Comment: I already did the line. I just want to now how to not cross the line. If I had to make another layout, it will make a lot of extra work. I just finish this activity, I would have to redesign the whole Activity.

Comment: If you set up the layout as I've described, it will be impossible to 'cross the line' because the EditText contains the text.

Comment: I already did it. I added a padding right in the edit text. now the text is not crossing the line. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Collin, this is a compound view. All those buttons are not inside text box. You can consider a LinerLayout using horizontal orientation. Here goes the layout hierarchy:

```
LinearLayout  (horizontal orientation)
|
+- EditText (fill parent)
|
+- LinearLayout (vertical orientation, width-30dp, gravity-right)
   |
   +- TextView (show remaining chars)
   | 
   +- Button
   | 
   +- Button
```

*Note: I am giving just an idea how you can layout views to achieve said goal. You might need to tweak a little.*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers. I did It. I added a imageview on the EditText. Then I added a padding right on the edittext to the text not to cross the line. One more time, Thank you very much for all the answers.